# oracle trigger query

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql, jobs, procedure

I have a trigger which is sending data from a table to another table in another database. all s working fine.

The prob  is that there is a new concept of `END DATE`, in which, if `END DATE` is present for a person, the row should reach the other table on that particular date..

**eg.: if someones end date is 31st august, it should go on that day only, but ofcourse, my trigger is firing on event change (when enddate is set to 31st august)..**

Could you please suggest me what I can do to SET the row to go on `ENDDATE`.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you don't want a trigger.  It sounds like you want a job.  For example, if you create a procedure that transfers all the rows whose `end_date` is today

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE move_rows_with_end_date(
  p_end_date IN DATE DEFAULT trunc(SYSDATE) 
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name@remote_database( <<list of columns>> )
    SELECT <<list of columns>>
      FROM table_name
     WHERE end_date = trunc(sysdate);
END;
```

Then you can create a job that runs the procedure every day at midnight

```
DECLARE
  l_jobno PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN move_rows_with_end_date; END;',
                   trunc(sysdate+1),
                   'trunc(sysdate+1)' );
  commit;
END;
```

Comment: actually Justin, the use of trigger was justified because i needed to send rows in realtime,before this whole end date concept came into place. But I'll try to place rows with end dates into this procedure-job and try..Thanks a lot for ur inputs